# How to programatically generate Bearer Token using Azure AD when Multifactor Authentication is enabled

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-active-directory

I am following the example https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless to authenticate a user against Azure AD in which the user sends his user credentials (uname,pwd) to acquire a bearer access Token(grant_type set to password). This token will be sent in the Authorization header to the internal Rest API. The REST API uses the token to get the details of the user using ClaimPrincipal and to authorize the user against AD Security group using Graph-API.

Now the problem is, we have Multi factor authentication (MFA) enabled, in this case how shall I able to generate the Token using Azure Oath APIs and get the above program to work.

Comment: The example you are giving is a non-interactive one, while an MFA-enabled account always needs extra interaction. These are 2 conflict designs. Hence, you either consider to use an interactive strategy or disable MFA.

Comment: I have similar issue. However, in my case I got the MFA disabled for one particular user. But now it has started giving me error as "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'GUID'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource"